# goroutine channels over a for loop

Tags: json, struct, go, channel

My `main` function reads json from a file, unmarshals it into a struct, converts it into another struct type and spits out formatted JSON through stdout.

I'm trying to implement goroutines and channels to add concurrency to my `for` loop.

```
func main() {
    muvMap := map[string]string{"male": "M", "female": "F"}
    fileA, err := os.Open("serviceAfileultimate.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fileA.Close()

    data := make([]byte, 10000)
    count, err := fileA.Read(data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dataBytes := data[:count]

    var servicesA ServiceA
    json.Unmarshal(dataBytes, &servicesA)
    var servicesB = make([]ServiceB, servicesA.Count)
    goChannels := make(chan ServiceB, servicesA.Count)

    for i := 0; i < servicesA.Count; i++ {
        go func() {
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Address").SetString(Merge(&servicesA.Users[i].Location))
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Date_Of_Birth").SetString(dateCopyTransform(servicesA.Users[i].Dob))
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Email").SetString(servicesA.Users[i].Email)
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Fullname").SetString(Merge(&servicesA.Users[i].Name))
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Gender").SetString(muvMap[servicesA.Users[i].Gender])
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Phone").SetString(servicesA.Users[i].Cell)
            reflect.ValueOf(&servicesB[i]).Elem().FieldByName("Username").SetString(servicesA.Users[i].Username)
            goChannels <- servicesB[i]
        }()
    }

    for index := range goChannels {
        json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(index)
    }

}
```

It compiles but is returning messages like:

```
goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main() C://.....go.94 +0x55b.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the channels info, not the data it contains. You don't want a loop, you just want to receive then print.

```
   json := <-index
   json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(json)
```

Now I do I need to point out, that code is not going to block. If you want to keep reading until all work is done you need some kind of locking/coordination mechanism.

You'll often see things like

```
for {
   select {
        case json := <-jsonChannel:
            // do stuff
        case <-abort:
            // get out of here 
   }
}
```

To deal with that. Also, just fyi you're initializing your channel with a default capacity (meaning it's a buffered channel) which is pretty odd. I'd recommend reviewing some tutorials on the topic cause overall your design needs some work actually be an improvement of non-concurrent implementations. Lastly you can find libraries to abstract some of this work for you and most people would probably recommend you do. Here's an example; https://github.com/lytics/squaredance

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Evan. I chose to use a buffered channel because I need to convert and print multiple structs. How would I do that without a buffered channel?

Comment: @ScottS. you can just use an array for those purposes. The idea of the channel is to provide communication between your worker threads and your application layer, you could use a buffered one, it's just rarely done and changes their mechanics a bit. Typically a channel blocks until it reads so you would use a for loop like the one I had above that just keeps reading off the channel until the goroutine says it's done or you get a shutdown or abort type of signal from elsewhere.

Comment: If you're going to use a buffered channel to just put an entire array into it you may as well not be using a goroutine at all, just use a blocking call cause you're not streaming your data at that point, you're just preparing it in asynchronously while doing nothing but waiting for it to be done.

Comment: I'll look into using an array as well as your for loop. Thanks for your time, Evan. I appreciate it.